# Getting error:-CS0433 IN ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I am getting error when i am publish my ASP.NET Application in localhost using IIS 7.5.
all the pages run perfectly expect on and getting error:-

> Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'pages_Default' exists in
>   both'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\785050d7\543e65af\assembly\dl3\6a3d3e87\242bc946_6834cf01\App_Web_zxwcuztt.DLL'
>   and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\785050d7\543e65af\assembly\dl3\c72e1cad\7d5dd447_6834cf01\App_Web_b5bhtyqt.DLL

Plese Help me to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

I set the batch="false" attribute on the compilation section in web.config worked for me.
This tells ASP.NET to dynamically compile individual `.aspx/.ascx` files into separate assemblies. This avoids the circular reference issue that triggers the exception.

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
       <compilation debug="false" batch="false"></compilation>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**Or**

You will have a path similar to the following:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

Delete the contents of this entire folder (no harm will be done), then try and Clean and Rebuild your solution.

**Or**

The problem occurred in a virtual application's bin folder. Looking into this bin-folder you will probably see two files (an information i found here):

`App_global.asax.dll`

`App_global.asax.compiled`

Removing these resolves the error. The `App_global.asax.dll` is generated at runtime too which causes the problem.

I am however still investigating how these files got there, so comments are definitely welcome!